Gravitational potential energy of a water column
If there is a water column of height $h$ from the ground level, then the gravitational potential energy should be $E=mgh/2$, since the height to the center of gravity is $h/2$. Now what I don't quite understand is if I want to find the velocity of water exiting from the bottom of the water column (at the ground level), assuming the energy is not lost, when using $mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ what should be taken for the height? Is it still the height to the center of gravity or the total height $h$? I have seen examples online where similar problems have been solved taking total height for potential energy. Which confuses me since when finding the P.E. of the water column alone, $h/2$ has to be taken.

Think about what happens to the location of the center of gravity of the column as the water exits the bottom.

it just goes from h/2 position to the ground level where h=0 right?

because $d(x^2)/dx = 2x$ not just $x$.

As the height drops, so does the velocity (and kinetic energy) of the water. Have you accounted for that?

You are correct that if you are considering the GPE of the whole column, then you should take $\frac h2$ because that is the average height of the water.
But when considering the water that is coming out, the water that is coming out is equivalent to the top layer dropping, the middle parts being replenished and all essentially drop out of the calculations by cancellation. So the GPE height of relevance is the full height.

Can you elaborate please? I don't quite get how things cancel out.

If the column of liquid has density $\rho$, cross-sectional area $A$ and height $h$ then its mass is $m = \rho A h$ and its PE is
$\displaystyle PE = \frac {mgh} 2 = \rho A g \left( \frac {h^2} 2 \right)$
If the column's initial height is $h_0$ and its final height is $h_1$ then the mass of liquid removed is
$\Delta m = \rho A (h_0 - h_1)$
and the change in PE of the column is
$\displaystyle \Delta PE = \rho A g \left( \frac {h_0^2-h_1^2} 2\right) = \rho A g \left( \frac {(h_0-h_1)(h_0+h_1)} 2\right) = (\Delta m) g \left( \frac {h_0+h_1} 2 \right)$
Note that $\frac {h_0+h_1} 2$ is the average of the initial and final heights of the column.

Let's consider a cylinder full of water that is $100 \ \text{m}$ high with a cross-sectional area of $2 \ \text{m}^2$, so the volume of water is $200 \ \text{m}^3$, and the mass is $200 \ \text{tonnes}$. The initial potential energy of the column of water is: $$\frac{mgh}{2} = 200\times g\times \frac{100}{2} = 10000 g.$$ If we drop the level by one meter, we remove $2$ tonnes of water from the total mass of the column of water, and the potential energy is now $$\frac{mgh}{2} = 198\times g\times \frac{99}{2} = 9801 g.$$ The change in potential energy is $\Delta \text{PE} + 199g$.
However, there is another way of looking at this. The $2 \ \text{m}^3$ of water that is missing from the top of the cylinder is now effectively at the bottom of the cylinder. We can consider only the change in the potential energy of that parcel of water. The initial potential energy of the parcel of water is $$mgh = 2\times g\times 99.5 = 199 g,$$ where $99.5$ is the height of the centre of mass of the parcel of water. The final potential energy of the parcel of water is $$mgh = 2\times g\times 0 = 0 g,$$ so the change in potential energy of the parcel is $\Delta \text{PE} = 199g$.
This is the same as the result we got when considering the average height of the total cylinder of water.
So, the seemingly contradictory methods are just two different ways of looking at the same thing, and both yield the same result. The height of $99.5$ that was used for the potential energy of the parcel of water is also the average of its upper height ($100$) and its lower height ($99$).

The velocity decreases as the column height falls
The total energy contained in the column is $mgh \over 2$. So, if we pull the plug and let the column drain out, then the total kinetic energy must be $mgh \over 2$.
If the velocity was constant over the draining period, you would indeed have $mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. However, it isn’t constant - it comes out much faster at the beginning than it does at the end.
When you initially pull the plug, the energy being converted is that as the column falls from $h$ to $h- \Delta h$ which is why you can the initial velocity will be $v=\sqrt {2gh}$, but as the height of the column drops, so does the speed at which it drains.
